# Update table with data from subquery dependant on table fields

Tags: sql

| email | user_id | tenant_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a@b.com | 1 | 2 |
| d@k.com | 3 | 7 |
| j@i.com | 23 | 7 |

I want to update this data based upon another computation I'll do with this data. Hence I tried :

```
update emails
    set email = Subquery.userEmails
    from (
        select CONCAT(
            Lower(users.first_name),
            '.', 
            Lower(users.last_name), 
            '.', 
            users.id::text, 
            '@',
            tenant_id::text,
            '.',
            users.language::text,
            '.com'
        ) as userEmails from users inner join tenants on users.tenant_id = tenants.id
    ) Subquery
```

I've tried this but apparently it does not pick the data from the row itself.

how can I manage to update `a@b.com` with the computation I'm done on the subquery, using the data from each row?

updated:

```
update emails
    set email = Subquery.userEmails
    from (
        select CONCAT(
            Lower(users.first_name),
            '.', 
            Lower(users.last_name), 
            '.', 
            users.id::text, 
            '@',
            emails.tenant_id::text,
            '.',
            users.language::text,
            '.com'
        ) as userEmails, user_id from users inner join emails on emails.user_id = users.id inner join tenants on emails.tenant_id = tenants.id 
    ) Subquery where emails.user_id = Subquery.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to join emails to subquery first, ie add `where emails.users_id=Subquery.user_id` or similar to the end.

otherwise you're probably looking to use `insert` not `update`

Comment: that hit my constraint, even though i think it still not going through each.

Comment: updated the code

Comment: does running your sub-query only, return the desired results? do these results match ids in the emails table?

Comment: Yes it does! I removed the constraint and ran it, the result was outrageous: it basically repeated the first row from the first result from the subquery in all of the other rows.

Comment: maybe if i tell what i want: i want to modify the email based upon some computation ill get from each row, but joining other columns. Is there a better way of doing that?